# display php result in specific div container

Tags: php, html, css

I have got this piece of code

```
$metric = 256*((10000000/$bandwidth)+($delay/10));
echo $metric;
```

I need the $metric value stores in specific div container which i have already created on a separate HTML form page.

[image]

Comment: `<div id="in-here"><?= $metric; ?></div>`

Comment: i guess you click calculate to get the result then you want to put it inside that div, well do an ajax call then print the result into the div using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please uses echo $metric; on where you want to print the result . like

```
  <div><?php echo $metric; ?></div>
```

Comment: Yes, as soon as i posted i figured out to include the php file in the div container and do an echo... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have two options :

#### in case you have the php and html form on the same file (or included):

then in the php code :

```
$metric = 256*((10000000/$bandwidth)+($delay/10));
```

in your html code :

```
<div id="somediv"> <?= $metric; ?> </div> <!-- shorter version is better -->
```

#### in case you have the php and html on separate files, you could use ajax for that.

then in your php code:

```
$bandwidth = $_GET['bandwidth'];
$delay     = $_GET['delay'];

//calculate the metric
$metric = 256*((10000000/$bandwidth)+($delay/10));

echo $metric;
```

in your html page :

```
$('#calcute_button_id').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your_php_file.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            bandwidth: $('#bandwidth_elem_id').val(),
            delay:     $('#delay_elem_id').val()
        }
    }).done(function(result) {
        $('#your_div_id').html('<p>' + result + '</p>');
    });
})
```